# Visual Studio Code stopped to connect to my VPS

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have configured the connections to a few VPS on VS Code and it all worked fine. Now one of them stopped to connect. I get in the output a repetition of the following sequence:

```
[10:28:33.318] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 63618 "worker-de1" bash
[10:28:33.322] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:28:34.560] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:28:34.561] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[10:28:38.178] > 7e8dd4d4fdfd: running
[10:28:38.204] > Acquiring lock on /root/.vscode-server/bin/31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4
> 533/vscode-remote-lock.root.31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533
[10:28:38.218] > Found existing installation at /root/.vscode-server/bin/31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43
> b8544550fbae4533...
> Checking /root/.vscode-server/.31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533.log and 
> /root/.vscode-server/.31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533.pid for a running
>  server
[10:28:38.234] > Looking for server with pid: 3130682
[10:28:38.245] > Found running server...
> 
> *
[10:28:38.261] > * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-lice
> nse) and
[10:28:38.475] > * the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacyst
> atement).
> *
> 
> Checking server status on port 32979 with wget
> failed: Connection refused.
> 7e8dd4d4fdfd: start
> exitCode==28==
> listeningOn==32979==
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==aarch64==
> vscodeArch==arm64==
> bitness==64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/0==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
[10:28:38.494] > 
> 7e8dd4d4fdfd: end
[10:28:38.496] Received install output: 
exitCode==28==
listeningOn==32979==
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==aarch64==
vscodeArch==arm64==
bitness==64==
tmpDir==/run/user/0==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====

[10:28:38.500] Server status check failed - waiting and retrying
```

At the end I get the following:

```
[10:39:41.779] > f660d45d2664: running
[10:39:42.079] > Acquiring lock on /root/.vscode-server/bin/31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4
> 533/vscode-remote-lock.root.31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533
[10:39:42.111] > Found existing installation at /root/.vscode-server/bin/31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43
> b8544550fbae4533...
> Checking /root/.vscode-server/.31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533.log and 
> /root/.vscode-server/.31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533.pid for a running
>  server
> Looking for server with pid: 3130682
> Found running server...
[10:39:42.246] >  
> *
[10:39:42.329] > * Visual Studio Code Server
[10:39:42.338] > *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-lice
> nse) and
```

And with this it stops.
I can still conect with Putty and the VPS works fine. What can I do to reestablish a successful connection in VS Code?

Checked a regular SSH connection which works.
Checked harddrive space with 13 G left.
VPS is responding normally otherwise.